# How to automatically relate Email with Account? (Outlook Integration)

Tags: salesforce-for-outlook, lightning-outlook

I enabled Outlook Integration:

[image]

with Enhanced Email with Outlook:

[image]

**Have an account with a custom field (theres no standard field) with this email in salesforce** and when receive a mail from the exact same email, The integration **doesnt find any relation to those records**! I think that its relating only with people. Why?

[![enter image description here][3]][3]

The panel has the Account section:

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The outlook add-in will suggest contacts, leads, or users based on the email recipient list and the standard email field in Salesforce. It will not be looking for Accounts to match based on a custom field as you're asking.

This [knowledge article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000313638&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1) goes over what it can and cannot do in terms of automatic searching. This, below, is directly from the article and answers your question:

**Can this search logic be customized?**
*Search parameters are not configurable at this time.*

**Is the domain in the email address used to find an account?**
*The email domain is not used at this time.*

**Are other email address fields used in the search?**
*The standard email address on Contact/Lead/User objects is used in the matching logic. Custom email address fields on those objects will also be considered.*

---

You can search for accounts in that search bar (or other objects) to relate the email to those records, but it will require you to search yourself.

Comment: Create a contact for every account who doesnt have a contact related? (As a workaround to avoid manual search)